# How To use db.collection.find() with a geospatial index and multiple filters on mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb

Im struggling to fix this statement. Im getting an error of illegal character. Can someone please help.

```
db.cities.find({ “population” : { $gt: 500000}},  {location:   { $geoWithin:   { $centerSphere: [ [ -83.067834, 42.357035], 400 / 3963 ] } } }, {“elevation”: 0, “region”: 0, “subregion” : 0, “location” : 0, “population” : 0})
```

Answer (score 0):

Change`”` and `”` to `"`.

Try:

```
db.cities.find({ "population" : { $gt: 500000},  "location":   { $geoWithin:   { $centerSphere: [ [ -83.067834, 42.357035], 400 / 3963 ] } } , "elevation": 0, "region": 0, "subregion" : 0, "location" : 0, "population" : 0})
```

Comment: getting an error: {unsupported projection option

Comment: I update the answer, you should hold all the criteria in a single object.